# Add Birthdate to Customer Account Details Manually by Code?

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

i have a birthdate in query string like:

```
?birthdate=1991-01-01
```

and my code as follows :

```
$customer->setWebsiteId(Mage::app()->getWebsite()->getId());
$customer->loadByEmail($email);
if (!$customer->getId()) {
    $customer->setEmail($email);
    $customer->setFirstname($name);
    $customer->setLastname($lastname);
    $customer->setPassword($password);
    $customer->setGender(
    Mage::getResourceModel('customer/customer')
        ->getAttribute('gender')
        ->getSource()
        ->getOptionId($gender)
    );
}
```

Same way i want like :

```
$customer->setBirthday($date);
```

Any Solution ?

Comment: whenever you have an object you are not aware of try $obj->getData() or $obj->debug() this will give more details.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The birthday field is actually called `dob`. Try:

```
$customer->setDob('1991-01-01');
```

Or add the following date code :

```
list($y, $m, $d) = explode('-', $birthday);

$date=date('m/j/Y', strtotime("$y-$m-$d"));

$customer->setDob($date);
```

Comment: Thanks, But it adds default date 1/1/1970
Why ?

Comment: nope i added following code

list($y, $m, $d) = explode('-', $birthday);

$date=date('m/j/Y', strtotime("$y-$m-$d"));

$customer->setDob($date);

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Matt. I modified your solution (because I also had trouble with 01-01-1970 dates). Maybe someone can use it:

```
        // $birthday format m/d/y -> convert to m-d-Y
        $datetime = DateTime::createFromFormat('m/d/y', $birthday);
        $customer->setDob($datetime->format('m-d-Y'));
        $customer->save();
```